# Show that $|\sin{a}-\sin{b}| \le |a-b| $ for all $a$ and $b$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality, functional-inequalities

I've recently been going over the mean value and intermediate value theorems, however I'm not sure where to start on this.

Answer (score 4):

The mean value theorem will do just fine.  Setting $f(x) = \sin(x)$, note that
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| = |f'(c)||x - y|
$$
for some value $c$.  Can we find an upper bound for $|f'(c)|$?

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to the application of the mean value theorem,
you can write
$$
\sin a - \sin b = 2 \sin \frac{a-b}2 \cos \frac{a+b}2 
$$
and use
$$
|\sin u| \le |u|
$$