# Why is $ \left| \frac{\sin(\theta+\epsilon)-\sin(\theta)}{\epsilon} \right| \leq 1$ true?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I am conducting an error analysis of some sensor measurements associated with uncertainties. I ended up with the equation $\mathcal{S}$ of the form below. I numerically simulated the equation and noticed that it is always bounded by $\pm 1$. Nonetheless, I need to prove that mathematically. So my question is why the following inequality holds for any $\theta$ and $\epsilon$:

$$ \left| \mathcal{S} = \frac{\sin(\theta+\epsilon)-\sin(\theta)}{\epsilon} \right| \leq 1. $$

Thanks.

Comment: mean value theorem

Comment: $$\sin a - \sin b=2\sin\left(\frac{a-b}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)$$

Comment: Minus the limit notation, this is basically the limit definition of the derivative for sine, which is cosine and is always less than or equal to 1

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: Duplicate: [Show that $|\sin{a}-\sin{b}| \le |a-b| $ for all $a$ and $b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009477).

Answer (score 0):

Since the function sinus is of classe C^\infty, then by the Lagrange's theorem there exists \lambda belongs to (\theta, \theta + \epsilon) such that

sin(\theta + \epsilon) - \sin(\theta) = \epsilon \sin(\lambda)

and by boundedness of sinus, you obtain the result.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).